# Multiple divs in absolute

Tags: css, image, html, position

I reached to a problem in my website.
My website is showing all the records in she same page, that each record calls the main div called "work" and inside of that one is calling another one called "worktitle".

I want the worktitle div stays like the image:
[Image](http://shapesolutions.eu5.org/shape.jpg)

But the problem is on the second row. The divs that belongs to the seconda row are in the same place as the first row.
Like you can see here:
[Website](http://www.shapesolutions.tk)

HTML Code

```
<div id="box1">
<?php do { ?>
 <div id="work">
 <a href="<?php echo $row_works['url']; ?>" target="new">
 <img src="images/<?php echo $row_works['image']; ?>" />
 <div class="worktitle">
 <span class="infotec"><?php echo $row_works['infotec']; ?><br/>
 <?php if ((isset($_GET['lang'])) && ($_GET['lang']=="en")) {
     echo $row_works['descriptionen']; }
     else {
         echo $row_works['descriptionpt'];
        } ?>
 </span>
 <span class="title"><?php echo $row_works['title']; ?></span>
 </div>
 </a>
 </div>
 <?php } while ($row_works = mysql_fetch_assoc($works)); ?>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
#work {
float: left;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width : 200px;
border: solid 1px #787879;
}

#work a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#work a:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#work img {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 9;
}

a img{
border: 0;
}
.worktitle {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    background-color: #787879;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.infotec {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:9px;
}
.title {
    text-align: right;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Please help me out.

Comment: Your links are broken, you should update them if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all id's must be unique in your html so change `#work` to `.work` then try giving it a relative position and aligning your description to the bottom.

```
.work{
   position: relative;
}
.worktitle {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```